# como obtener números random de cuatro cifras cuyas cifras no se repitan? ejemplo 2714 diferente de 2712 que repite el 2

Tags: c++, dev-c++

en este programa obtengo los números random , luego convierto cada cifra de este mismo en una variable y las comparo para ver si alguna de las cifras se repite ;si al evaluarla alguno se repite vuelve al inicio para obtener un nuevo numero random para que así solo me de aquellos que no tengan cifras repetidas y lo que yo quiero lograr es que directamente los números que de aleatoriamente no contengan cifras repetidas sin tener que evaluarlos.

```
int n ,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6,n7;

main(){     
    
    st:
    n=1000+rand()%9999;
  
    n1=n%10;
    
    n2=n%100;
    n3=(n2-n2%10)/10;
    
    n4=n%1000;
    n5=(n4-n4%100)/100;
    
    n6=n%10000;
    n7=(n6-n6%1000)/1000;
  
    
    if(n1==n3 or n1==n5 or n1==n7){
        
        cout<<"\nLa cifra"<<":"<<n1<<" esta repetida"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        goto st;
        
    }else{ goto st1;
    }
    
    if(n3==n1 or n3==n5 or n3==n7){
        
        cout<<"\nLa cifra"<<":"<<n3<<" esta repetida"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        goto st;
        
    }else{ goto st1;
    }
    
    if(n5==n1 or n5==n3 or n5==n7){
        
        cout<<"\nLa cifra"<<":"<<n5<<" esta repetida"<<endl;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
        goto st;
    
    }else{ goto st1;
    }
    
    if(n7==n1 or n7==n3 or n7==n5){
        
     cout<<"\nLa cifra"<<":"<<n7<<" esta repetida"<<endl;
     system("pause");
     system("cls");
     goto st;
    
    }else{ goto st1;
    }
    
    st1:
     
    cout<<"\nes lo que querias"<<":"<<n<<endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
     goto st;
    
  
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma sencilla de lograr esto es usando un array para saber que dígitos ya usaste y que dígitos no.
La idea es que generes 4 dígitos únicos, y que por cada uno que vaya saliendo lo multipliques por `1000`, `100`, `10` o `1` dependiendo de la posición del dígito, y ese valor agregarlo a un resultado global que es tu número de 4 dígitos.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
  // Arreglo para guardar que dígitos han salido. Solo hay 9 dígitos.
  int digits[9];
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    digits[i] = 0;

  int multiplier = 1000;
  int result = 0;
  while (multiplier > 0) {
    int randomDigit = (rand() % 9) + 1;
    // Si el número aleatorio ya apareció, busquemos otro.
    if (digits[randomDigit] == 1)
      continue;

    digits[randomDigit] = 1;
    result += randomDigit * multiplier;
    multiplier /= 10;
  }

  std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias quedo super claro y conciso

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre una variante del código de Jacobo. En lugar de intentar forzosamente que salga un número que **no está** en el arreglo, mejor hacer lo contrario: **hacer que salga un número que sí está en un arreglo**.

Puedes crear una función que genere un arreglo con los números que todavía no salieron y con `rand` obtener un índice aleatorio que corresponda a algún dígito en dicho arreglo.

```
#include <iostream>

int availableDigits(bool usedDigits[], int storage[], int start){
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < 10; i++)
        if (!usedDigits[i])
            storage[j++] = i;

    return j;
}

int main() {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
  
    bool usedDigits[10];
    int avDigits[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        usedDigits[i] = false;

    int nDigits = 4;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nDigits; i++) {
        int nAvailable = availableDigits(usedDigits, avDigits, i == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        int randomDigit = avDigits[rand() % nAvailable];

        usedDigits[randomDigit] = true;
    
        result *= 10;
        result += randomDigit;
    }

    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

Me tomé la libertad de agregar el dígito 0. Como el dígito más significativo se genera primero, en el primer ciclo se le dice a la función que excluya el 0 comenzando desde el 1 con el tercer parámetro: `i == 0 ? 1 : 0`.

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##dVLLTsMwELznK5YiJJsUKZW4kKQgJI4VN06Qg5u4kavErvzoBfXbg19N0kj4Yu/ueGZn7fp0emrrehjuGa8701AomVBaUtK/JgnjGsiZsI7sO/rBWqYV2gvRgVG0CfF3tQYHU1pI0tIpJFLj3wTscvERtpAVPjwICcjlmM15XGGPJWwyu6cp9iB/7wDobqbEqqnm1lXymKaVpWJF4suSaiM5HIvkEhz0hHGEITSjJOENQoYr1nLaYM16ij6/djuMXXses7S4yapidELOy@yNoSyYeVl4ubFhYQfSKRobdld5KNrK8yQlqTKd/mdyUSheDHLR40j6fn07i1@@49TRevS0dsyWGt5gAzlkuLjhc6MTvYd6wmjITxTDw0yvitYW1mcEbghaGhoURnC0/Lh132GZTbfzFkL5EoSUbvK8FkZDWV7h9rT64Sv7D4bhDw).