# Como dar valores aleatorios que no se repitan en un array (para barajar cartas e inicializar un mazo) C++

Tags: c++

El objetivo sería crear una baraja de cartas y una vez creada barajarla y sacar una carta (es para un juego de blackjack). He intentado hacer algo tal que así:

```
int fila, columna, mazo [fila][columna] ;

//Creamos el mazo con un array

for (fila = 0; fila < 4 ; fila ++ ){

    for (columna = 0; columna < 10; columna ++){
        mazo [fila][columna] = 40;
    }
}
srand(time(NULL));
 /*Prueba para mostrar el mazo*/ cout << mazo [fila][columna];
```

Este es mi intento pero no funciona, por favor me podrían dar una solución, gracias!

Comment: Sugiero algo como [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/568998/169744) que hice hace poco. Sería cuestión de adaptarlo. Básicamente que en un arreglo guardes los números (o cartas) que ya salieron y generes otro con los que aún no.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes implementar una pila estática que más o menos sería asi:

```
struct Carta{
    int palo, numero;
};
int tope;
Carta baraja[52];

void mezclar(){
    for(int i= 0; i< 52; ++i){
        int j= rand()% 52;
        Carta temp= baraja[i];
        baraja[i]= baraja[j];
        baraja[j]= temp;
    }
}
void inicializar(){
    //13 cartas de 4 palos diferentes
    for(int i= 0; i< 4; ++I){
        for(int j= 0; j< 13; ++j){
            baraja[i*13+j].palo= i+1;
            baraja[i*13+j].numero= j+1;
        }
    }
    tope= 52;
}
Carta sacar_carta(){ //equivalente a pop
    tope--;
    return baraja[tope];
    //se asume que en ningún caso sacaras más de 52 cartas
}
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    //estas funciones siempre se llaman una después de la otra
    inicializar();
    mezclar();
    //si necesitas una carta simplemente haces:
    //Carta carta;
    //carta= sacar_carta() ;
    //continúa la lógica de tu juego
    return 0;
}
```

Es lo más simple que te puedo exponer mi idea.

Comment: Dos cartas no pueden tener el mismo valor porque entonces ya no puedes distinguirlas entre sí. Si le das a dos cartas el valor 5 y piensas, como una está en la fila de los bastos y la otra en la de espadas, está claro ... si claro, pero después de mezclar resulta que te encuentras dos 5 seguidos en la misma fila ... ¿cual es cual?

Comment: Se ha editado el código de ejemplo para que contemple también el palo de cada carta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, no deberías crear un array con valores no constantes, mucho menos si estos valores no constantes no están inicializados:

```
int fila, columna, mazo [fila][columna];
//  ~~~~  ~~~~~~~
//    ^      ^  no están inicializadas
```

Con esto, en los casos en los que compile, estarás creando un array de un tamaño que desconoces (piensa que tanto `fila` como `columna` pueden tener valor inicial 0 o incluso un valor negativo) y eso a muy seguro va a impactar negativamente en tu programa.

Por otro lado, la opción más sencilla puede ser rellenar el array con los valores ordenados y a continuación ejecutas un algoritmo que *mezcle* esos valores:

```
// Rellenamos el mazo
int mazo[40];
for (int carta= 0; carta < 40; carta++ )
{
    mazo[carta] = carta++;
}

// Mezclamos las cartas
std::random_device dev;
std::mt19937 rnd(dev());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(40);

// Recorremos todo el mazo
for(int i=0; i<40; i++)
{
    // Calculamos el índice de otra carta para mezclar
    int index = dist(rnd);

    // Mezclamos
    int carta = mazo[i];
    mazo[i] = mazo[index];
    mazo[index] = carta;
}
```

Fijate que he optado por un array simple en vez de usar una matriz. En el fondo tu estás manejando un mazo de cartas, y eso se parece más a una única pila que a 4 pilas independientes. Tener una única colección lineal simplifica la gestión de la misma, de la misma forma que los algoritmos que tengas que implementar (como el de mezcla) serán igualmente más sencillos